# Feels like ABS kicks in when braking

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, sensor, abs, braking

For the past week, my car (a Hyundai Tucson 2016 and 80 000 miles) started doing like ABS kicks in when braking, but rarely. It feels like when you're braking on ice (pedal starts vibrating) for 1 second. The ABS light isn't on or any non normal lights in the dashboard. It happens at slow speed or higher speed, but since it does that for a second, it doesn't stop me from braking for now at all, but I don't want to wait that long.

Any ideas why it's happening? I checked the pads, they're more than fine (almost new) and the rotors could be replaced soon, but it's really in the brake pedal that this vibration/ABS-ish situation is happening, I don't feel it anywhere else in the car.

The ABS light never came on when this is happening. So maybe it's not ABS at all...but I'm just comparing it to it when that happens.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Probably a silly question but are your tires all inflated to the same pressure?

Comment: Yes they are all inflated the same pressure (just checked this week). Thanks!

Comment: What type of vehicle and how many miles on the odometer?

Comment: Added to the post (a Hyundai Tucson 2016, and 80 000 miles). Thanks

Comment: Based on your description, a scanner that reads wheel sensor speeds could be used to confirm all sensors are reporting the same speed. I would think it should turn on the ABS light on if they weren't, but that's the first place I'd look.

Comment: There is the possibility it is a bad wheel bearing.  The worn bearing can allow  inconsistent  movement of the tone ring relative to the sensor. This can activate the ABS  module but not set a fault light.

Comment: @mikes I would add that as a possible answer, I have seen this on couple of occasions.

Answer (score 1):

I’d check your shock absorbers - I had one fail and as the wheel bounced on bumps the ABS would kick in.  I’d noticed the ABS but didn’t realise there was a shock absorber problem until I was following behind the car and saw a wheel bouncing.

Answer (score 1):

There is the possibility it is a bad wheel bearing. The worn bearing can allow inconsistent movement of the tone ring relative to the sensor. This can activate the ABS module but not set a fault light. –